# Overwrite pie chart each time with a new one on clicking a button

Tags: javafx-8

I have a form with input boxes and a button. On clicking the button, some calculations are performed and the output is displayed as a pie chart. If I change the input values and click the button again, the new chart just comes above the old one and I'm not able to clear the old one. How to remove the old one so that only the latest chart is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Made a lot of assumptions about your code because of not having any samples of what you have already, but you could try doing the following. HTH

```
@FXML PieChart piechart;

@FXML
private void buttonClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    PieChart newPieChart = createPieChart(...);
    piechart.setVisible(false);
    piechart = newPieChart;
    //Code to add the pie chart to your window
}
```